# Array "sometimes" not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, outerhtml

I am trying to implement a button that will delete events from a users selected set of events. For troubleshooting sakes right now I have 5 events hard coded in the page, but eventually they are called from localStorage. The delete button is supposed to delete elements from localStorage as well as the page. My problem is it throws an error when the Remove buttons are not clicked in order. Any and all help is appreciated. To see the errors please open console. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roob/65j6ktnL/

here's a shorter version of the code:

```
<div id="result">
    <div class="10am target-stage stage-only saturday  eventer" id="row0" rel="0">
        <table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">    
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" class="ev-time" style="border:none;">10:30 a.m.</td>
                <td valign="top" class="ev-desc">
                <span class="info"><p class="ev-date">SATURDAY, APRIL. 18, 2015<br /><span class="ev-title"><b>Children&rsquo;s Stage</b></span><br /><span class="ev-signings">Signing Area 1</span></p></span>
                <span class="info-body"><b>Anna Dewdney, </b>Author of<em> NELLY GNU AND DADDY TOO</em></span>
                <span class="info-btn"><p class="selctor" rel="0"><span class="addSchd"><a href="#"><b>+ MY SCHEDULE</b></a></span>
                <span class="mapit" ><a href="#"><b>map</b></a></span>
                <span class="premove hidden" rel="0"><a href="#">Remove</a></span></p></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="11am target-stage stage-only saturday eventer" id="row1" rel="1">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" class="ev-time" style="border:none;">11:00 a.m. </td>
                <td valign="top" class="ev-desc">
                <span class="info"><p class="ev-date">SATURDAY, APRIL. 18, 2015<br /><span class="ev-title"><b>Children&rsquo;s Stage</b></span></p></span>
                <span class="info-body"><b>Yuyi Morales, </b>Author of<em> NIÑO WRESTLES THE WORLD</em></span>
                <span class="info-btn"><p class="selctor" rel="1"> <span class="addSchd"><a href="#"><b>+ MY SCHEDULE</b></a></span>
                <span class="mapit" > <a href="#"><b>map</b></a></span>
                <span class="premove hidden" rel="1"><a href="#">Remove</a></span></p></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="11am target-stage stage-only saturday eventer" id="row2" rel="2">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:none;">     
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" class="ev-time" style="border:none;">11:30 a.m. </td>
                <td valign="top" class="ev-desc">
                <span class="info"><p class="ev-date">SATURDAY, APRIL. 18, 2015<br /><span class="ev-title"><b>Children&rsquo;s Stage</b></span><br /><span class="ev-signings">Signing Area 4</span></p></span>
                <span class="info-body"><em>Scooby-Doo and the Carnival Creep,</em> presented by <b>Warner Bros. Consumer Products</b></span>
                <span class="info-btn"><p class="selctor" rel="2"> <span class="addSchd"><a href="#"><b>+ MY SCHEDULE</b></a></span>
                <span class="mapit"><a href="#"><b>map</b></a></span>
                <span class="premove hidden" rel="2"><a href="#">Remove</a></span></p></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div></div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var storaged = Object.keys(localStorage);
        var storageLength = storaged.length;

            for (var i=0; i<storageLength; i++)
            {
                var el = $(localStorage[storaged[i]]);
                $("#result").append(el);
            }

        $("#buttn2").click(function(){
        localStorage.clear();
        $("#result").html('');
        console.log("Storage is cleared");
        });

        $(".premove").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var a=$(this).attr("rel");
          console.log(a);
          var eventsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("eventer");
          var eventSelctd=(eventsArray[a]).outerHTML;
          localStorage.removeItem("schedule " + a, eventSelctd);
          eventsArray[a].outerHTML="";
          });
      });           
    </script>
```

Comment: It's because the `rel` attributes are hardcoded.  When you remove, say, item 2, items 3 and 4 are now items 2 and 3, so if you remove 4 and it goes to look for the 4th element in the array, it's not there.  You need to rethink this logic somewhat.  Either the `rel` attributes are updated on the fly, or you use different logic to identify which one has been clicked.  Even better, investigate the use of something like knockout or angular and the templating options they provide.

Comment: there are much simpler ways to traverse than your `rel` approach. Look at jQuery closest() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `rel=(number)` to each item in the list and using that number to get its reference in the array defined by `document.getElementsByClassName("eventer")` - each time you remove an item the array gets shorter because the removed item is now gone and you redefine it with each click of the remove button. What happens is you eventually start looking for item #4 and it isn't there because only two items exist in the list.

Another way to do this would be to look for the element closest to your button and remove it.

```
var eventSelected = $(this).closest('.eventer'); 
localStorage.removeItem("schedule " + a, eventSelected[0]);
eventSelected.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations. lemieuxster your code worked, thank you. I use the rel logic on another page to add the events to localStorage, so i thought reversing that methodology would work here, obviously not. @James I am exploring Angular for this project as we speak, I needed to make this work for the existing structure in case management does not like my angular suggestion  :)  thanks again